# Android Java Development Multiple Tables in SQLite

Tags: java, android

EDIT:
Might be worth adding that i created 4/5 tables in separate java classes, is this the correct way of doing things or should all tables be created in 1 class?

Okay i had multiple tables running and working on my app. I was told to wipe the data from the app if i wanted to add a new table which has been working so far.

Also adding the if statement checking the oldversion==1 method which also worked.

I tried to add a new table and suddenly half of my tables don't work. Some do and some don't and its very inconsistent.

This code is what i used to successfully run my table before the wipe however it won't create the table as it cannot find the table named "Achievements"

EDIT 2:
I HAVE PUT ALL THE TABLES IN 1 CLASS BUT I STILL GET THE SAME ERROR:

MyDb.java

package com.gofitness.www;

```
      import java.sql.SQLException;

        import android.content.ContentValues;
          import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
         import android.util.Log;

          public class MyDb {
public static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
     public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
 public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_CALORIES = "calories";
public static final String KEY_PROTEIN = "protein";
public static final String KEY_CARBS = "carbs";
public static final String KEY_FATS = "fats";
public static final String KEY_ACHID = "AchievementID";
public static final String KEY_COMPLETED = "Completed";
public static final String KEY_ACH = "Achievement";
public static final String TAG = "MyDb";



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GoFitness";    
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String Create_Users =
    "create table users (userid integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "username text not null, password text not null);";


     private static final String Create_Stats =
      "create table stats (userid integer primary key autoincrement, "
     + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
       KEY_AGE + " INT NOT NULL, " +
      KEY_CALORIES + " INT NOT NULL, " +
       KEY_WEIGHT + " INT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_HEIGHT + " INT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_PROTEIN + " INT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_FATS + " INT NOT NULL, " +
       KEY_CARBS + " INT NOT NULL);";



    private static final String Create_Achievements =
    "create table achievements (AchievementID integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "Achievement text not null);";

     private static final String Create_UserAchievements =
     "create table userachievements (userid integer, "
     + "AchievementID integer not null, Completed text not null);";




     private Context context;
     private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
      private SQLiteDatabase db;

     public MyDb(Context ctx) 
    {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL(Create_Users);
    db.execSQL(Create_Stats);
    db.execSQL(Create_Achievements);
    db.execSQL(Create_UserAchievements);
      }


 @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                       int newVersion) 
 {
     Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
           + " to "
           + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users,stats,achievements,userachievements");
     onCreate(db);
       }
      }


     public MyDb open() throws SQLException 
    {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     return this;
        } 

       //---closes the database---    
      public void close() 
       {
       DBHelper.close();
        }



    public long createEntry(String usernamevar, String agevar,String  
            weightvar,String heightvar,String caloriesvar,
            String proteinvar, String carbsvar, String fatvar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_USERNAME,usernamevar);
        cv.put(KEY_AGE,agevar);
        cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT,weightvar);
        cv.put(KEY_HEIGHT,heightvar);
        cv.put(KEY_CALORIES,caloriesvar);
        cv.put(KEY_PROTEIN,proteinvar);
        cv.put(KEY_CARBS,carbsvar);
        cv.put(KEY_FATS,fatvar);



           return db.insert("stats", null, cv);
          }

    public long createUA(String check, String checkpass, String completedDB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ACHID,check);
        cv.put(KEY_USERID,checkpass);
        cv.put(KEY_COMPLETED,completedDB);

        return db.insert("userachievements",null, cv);

    }


    public long createAch(String check) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ACH,check);

        return db.insert("achievements",null, cv);

    }




    public long createUser(String check, String checkpass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_USERNAME,check);
        cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD,checkpass);
        return db.insert("users",null, cv);

    }



    public String getName(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                "users" +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();

                 int iUsername = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);
                    String Name = c.getString(iUsername);


                    return Name;

            }
        return null;
    }


    public String getPass(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                "users" +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();

                 int iPassword = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD);
                    String Pass = c.getString(iPassword);


                    return Pass;



            }
        {
            return null;

        }
    }

    public String getId(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                "users" +
                " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

        if (c != null ) {
            c.moveToFirst();

                 int iPassword = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERID);
                    String ID = c.getString(iPassword);


                    return ID;



            }
        {
            return null;

        }
    }



          }
```

Achievements.java

```
    package com.gofitness.www;

       import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
         import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.EditText;
       import android.widget.TextView;

      public class Achievements extends Activity  {


Button submit;
TextView invalid;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle login) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(login);
setContentView(R.layout.text);

 Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
 final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
 final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
 final TextView invalid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invalid);
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         boolean diditwork = true;
        try {
        String check = username.getText().toString();
        String checkpass = password.getText().toString();

    AddAchievements entry = new AddAchievements(Achievements.this);
    entry.open();
    entry.createEntry(check, checkpass);
    entry.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
            diditwork=false;
            }finally{
        if(diditwork){
        invalid.setText("WERKZ");
        }
            }


        }
```

AddAchievements.java

```
          package com.gofitness.www;

         import android.content.ContentValues;
         import android.content.Context;
         import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

       public class AddAchievements {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "AchievementID";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Achievement";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gofitness";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Achievements";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


private DbHelper ourHelper;
Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{





    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + 
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (oldVersion==1){


                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +   
                DATABASE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
                }}

}
public AddAchievements(Context c)
{
    ourContext = c; 
}

public AddAchievements open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;


}
public void close(){
ourHelper.close();  
}

public long createEntry(String check, String checkpass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,check);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null, cv);

}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iUser = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);


    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

    result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iUser) +"\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String getName(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
            DATABASE_TABLE +
            " where username = "+ "'"+ s+"'" , null);

    if (c != null ) {
        c.moveToFirst();

             int iUsername = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
                String Name = c.getString(iUsername);


                return Name;

        }
    return null;
}


    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to why these are not working i will be very appreciative. 
Thank you

```
  });


}
```

}

Comment: Do you have another class that also create database?

Comment: Do all tables belong to the same database?

Comment: All tables belong to the same database however i set a class for each table to be created within. So the above code is extremely similar to my other 4 tables i have set up all called within a menu.

Comment: Just a thought I would really recommend going with this if you have more or less complex structure of your db http://ormlite.com/

Comment: Please be a bit more specific what goes wrong. Which method doesn't yield the desired result? What result does it yield instead? Anything to see in logcat? Did the onUpgrade method run through? There are tons of possibilities. Also the formatting of your code is less from ideal for us understanding it and spotting problems easily.